# React Native FlatList separator between columns

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList with multiple columns:

```
    <FlatList
      numColumns={4}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
      ...
    </FlatList>
```

And a line separator:

```
  renderSeparator = () => (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        height: 0.5,
      }}
    />
  );
```

But the separator only appear between rows, not between columns (even if i add             `width: 0.5`

[View on expo](https://snack.expo.io/r171a0PwZ)

Comment: I would better use gap in columnWrapperStyle

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you can just add if else condition inside renderItems and check the index modulus to add separator.. I just use this one and everything works great.

something like :-

```js
_renderItem = ({item,index}) => {
   return(
      <View style={[{ backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1 }, index%2==0 ? { marginRight: 10 } : { marginLeft: 10 } ]}>
         <Text>{item.key}</Text>
      </View>
   )
}
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 10):

Incase anyone runs into this in the future, I discovered an alternative using flexbox.

A FlatList accepts a columnwrapperStyle so a style of justifyContent: 'space-around' would do

and then for the element returned in the renderItem give a flex divisible by 1 so if the numColumns is 2 you'd set the flex for the renderItem to be about 0.45

```
<FlatList
numColumns={2}
ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
              <View style={{ backgroundColor: "green", height: 2 }} />
            )}
 columnWrapperStyle={{
       justifyContent: "space-between",
     }}
renderItem={({item, index}) => <View style={{flex: 0.45, height: 120, backgroundColor: '#dedede' }}>
<Text>{index}</Text>
</View>}
/>
```

Comment: I used the following to get a nice gap between the columns.

```columnWrapperStyle={{ gap: 5 }}```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I also did not find a way to add a column separator using properties in the flatlist component. So I just added the view outside the text component in the render item like this:

```
export default class App extends Component {

 render() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.view}>
    <FlatList
      data={['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']}
      numColumns={4}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.separator}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
   </View>
  );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 view: {
  paddingTop: 30,
 },
 text: {
  flex: 1,
  fontSize: 40,
  textAlign: 'center'
 },
 separator: {
  flex: 1, 
  borderWidth: 1, 
  borderColor: 'red'
 },
});
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result from the sample code above.]

I hope this is can help you. :)

Comment: This would create border around the top, bottom, left and right bounds rather than just between the items.

Comment: I agree with @Avery235 - This is not the right approach.

Comment: thats a very brilliant idea, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am bit to the party but I ran into same problem and solved this problem by using this renderRow code. I have 2 columns in grid view. Please change column length by replacing X in *index % X === 0* and *index <= Y* where Y is columns-1

```
renderRow({ item, index }) {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.GridViewContainer, 
                    index % 2 === 0 ? {
                      borderLeftWidth: 1, borderLeftColor: 'black',
                      borderRightWidth: 1, borderRightColor: 'black',} 
                      : 
                      {borderRightWidth: 1, borderRightColor: 'black'}

                      ,{borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'black'}
                      ,index <= 1 && {borderTopWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'black'}
                    ]}
      >

      ... render item code ...
        </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a View wrapper around your Text component and apply borderRight style to the View component, see example here:　https://snack.expo.io/HJx68bKvb, try run in the Android emulator on Expo, the Expo's iOS emulator for some reason is not showing the border correctly, but is working on my local emulator.

You can play around with padding on View component and Text component to get the desired border position.

Comment: This would create a right border at the very end of each row as well.

Comment: @Avery235 Updated my answer to address the right border at the very end of each row issue.

Answer (score 0):

I watched [your Expo](https://snack.expo.io/r171a0PwZ). It is as below.

```
 1   2   3   4 
---------------
 5   6   7   8
```

I assume you want as below.

```
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 
---+---+---+---
 5 | 6 | 7 | 8
```

To do this, It is not possible with `ItemSeparatorComponent` only.
as Hazim Ali says, use different style per index.

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <Text style={[styles.text, index % 4 !== 0 && {borderLeftWidth: 1, borderLeftColor: 'red'}]}>{item}</Text>
    )}
```

[image]

[This is the complete example](https://snack.expo.io/rJUcuSR7M).

--

> But the separator only appear between rows, not between columns

As far as I read the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.48.4/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js#L523-L539), 
when numColumns > 2, there is no itemseparator between columns.
Itemseparator is only between row and row.

Here is example.
When numColumns is set 4, four items are grouped to one cell.
And one itemSeparator is put between cells.

```
 1   2   3   4  <- cell1
--------------- <- itemSeparator
 5   6   7   8  <- cell2
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Add another view with background color and width using the index value of flatlist**

I have 4 values in index so I passed the separator view upto index 3 using index-3.

```
                     <FlatList
                      data={status_project}
                      horizontal={true}
                      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                        return (
                          <>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                              onPress={() => {
                                this.setState({ status_selection: index });
                                console.log("Pressed");
                              }}
                            >
                              <View
                                style={{
                                  marginHorizontal: 2,
                                  paddingVertical: 5,
                                }}
                              >
                                <View
                                  style={{
                                    backgroundColor:
                                      this.state.status_selection === index
                                        ? "#fff"
                                        : "transparent",
                                    paddingVertical: 10,
                                    borderRadius: 8,
                                    width: windowWidth / 4 - 8,
                                    height: 40,
                                    alignItems: "center",
                                  }}
                                >
                                  <Text
                                    style={[
                                      { textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold" },
                                      {
                                        color:
                                          this.state.status_selection === index
                                            ? Colors.primary_color
                                            : "black",
                                      },
                                    ]}
                                  >
                                    {item.title}
                                  </Text>
                                </View>
                              </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <View
                              style={{
                                backgroundColor:
                                  index - 3 ? Colors.tab_bar_color : "transparent",
                                width: 0.5,
                              }}
                            ></View>
                          </>`
                        );
                      }}
                    />
```

Answer (score -1):

> **This will help you:**

```
<FlatList
      data={['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']}
      numColumns={4}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
      renderItem={({ item ,index}) => (
        <>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
        <View
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor:
                          index - 3 ? 'red': "transparent",
                        width: 0.5,
                      }}
                    ></View>
                    </>
      )}
    />
```

Answer (score -2):

You can provide a margin for each item and a negative margin for the container. This is a very common trick for CSS flex layout.

```
  renderItem = (sale) => {
    const {item, index} = sale;
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'#f00', margin:20}}>  ### LOOK AT HERE ###
      </View>
    )
  };

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={{flex:1,}} >
      <FlatList
        style={{ margin:-20}}   ### LOOK AT HERE ###
        data={this.state.sales}
        numColumns={2}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    </View>
    )
  }
```

[Click here to see my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vonOU.png)